# How to soft-restart Windows Server 10 Technical Preview (renamed Insider Preview)?

Tags: windows

Windows 10 Server TP has a new feature called "soft-restart" that claims to go back to bootloader without resetting devices thus resulting in a faster reboot.

How do I actually invoke a soft-restart?

Searching product installed help yields no results, and I could not find online product documentation.

[image]

Comment: http://fpaste.org/151256/61554131/ - this is the output from the two commands

Comment: I wonder if such a feature merits the fuzz: If you ever come into a situation where a *server* OS needs rebooting, a few extra seconds from device resets should not cause much worry ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Rolling out cluster-aware updates to a farm of two hundred servers? We might be talking cumulatively *hours* of time off of that process.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It's not a few extra seconds. On some servers (e.g. HP Proliant) it could be 5 to 15 minutes!

Comment: so apparently this has been eventually pulled back from server 2016 and delayed for until server 2019[1]; currently in the latest insider build the commands exists but they take you through a full POST initialization.   

[1] https://web.archive.org/web/20181211135310/https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/F/0/BF00B689-94F5-4E12-8159-7804D0C27C09/Windows_Server_2019_Feature_Comparison_Guide_EN_US.pdf

Answer (score 9):

```
C:\> shutdown.exe /soft /r /t 0
```

For a "soft" reboot. The `/t 0` simply means "do it immediately (0-second delay.)"

You will also find the Powershell equivalent is:

```
Restart-Computer -Soft
```

But of course, the -Soft parameter is not documented yet, because tech preview.

Comment: I have tried both shutdown and powershell solutions, the command line switches are accepted but the machine does a regular reboot instead. I will wait to mark the answer as accepted until this really works. Perhaps is this due to nature of technical preview of the software. Has anyone actually *tried* performing a soft restart to confirm the feature is implemented and, if it worked, what is the build number on which it worked?

Comment: While this feature was available in some older technical previews of Server 2016, it is not available in the last one (TP5) and it is doubtful it will make it into the final version. Maybe sometime later?