# Restart Windows without restarting computer

Tags: windows

It was possible in Windows 95, you had to press SHIFT while click Restart.

And it possible in Linux with kexec.

How to restart modern Windows Server without restarting BIOS and bootloader?

Comment: Maybe this http://serverfault.com/questions/644741/how-to-soft-restart-windows-server-10-technical-preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soft Reboot is available on Server 2016 Technical Preview and will be available in Server 2016 (likely released after Ignite). With PowerShell, the cmdlet is `Restart-Computer -Soft`

This functionality however is not available on other Windows Operating Systems (eg. Server 2012R2, Windows 10).

Comment: While this feature was available in some older technical previews of Server 2016, it is not available in the last one (TP5) and it is doubtful it will make it into the final version. Maybe sometime later?